# This HTML fails to run the alert() script. Why? Yes. jquery is installed in the correct relative location

Tags: javascript, html

The system at JSFiddler seems to think this is Ok too, but won't display the alert either. http://jsfiddle.net/dmafackler/zEEpB/3/

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>foobar</title>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js" />
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() { alert("Is anybody home?"); });
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <p>Copasetic.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why don't self-closing script tags work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/69913/why-dont-self-closing-script-tags-work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`<script>` tags aren't self-closing. You need to provide a closing tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
```

If you don't, the HTML isn't parsed correctly:

[image: bad html]

Comment: stackoverflow.com/questions/69913 covers this well too.